# json data in grouped bar chart

Tags: javascript, php, json

This is the url json data

```
[{"call_time":"0","total_inc_traffic":"1363.10","total_out_traffic":"88.70"},
{"call_time":"1","total_inc_traffic":"479.57","total_out_traffic":"36.98"}, 
{"call_time":"2","total_inc_traffic":"239.57","total_out_traffic":"13.43"},
{"call_time":"3","total_inc_traffic":"190.28","total_out_traffic":"8.20"}, 
{"call_time":"4","total_inc_traffic":"223.80","total_out_traffic":"0.00"}, 
{"call_time":"5","total_inc_traffic":"158.87","total_out_traffic":"19.58"}, 
{"call_time":"6","total_inc_traffic":"27.52","total_out_traffic":"36.18"}, 
{"call_time":"7","total_inc_traffic":"47.70","total_out_traffic":"69.57"}, 
{"call_time":"8","total_inc_traffic":"2234.35","total_out_traffic":"137.60"}, 
{"call_time":"9","total_inc_traffic":"150.67","total_out_traffic":"162.07"}, 
{"call_time":"10","total_inc_traffic":"4497.05","total_out_traffic":"267.32"}, 
{"call_time":"11","total_inc_traffic":"5049.87","total_out_traffic":"242.42"}, 
{"call_time":"12","total_inc_traffic":"5227.67","total_out_traffic":"286.88"}, 
{"call_time":"13","total_inc_traffic":"3384.30","total_out_traffic":"360.88"}, 
{"call_time":"14","total_inc_traffic":"3650.73","total_out_traffic":"328.28"}]
```

How to show this json data in a grouped bar graph. The bar graph can be any bar graph. Please help

Comment: You must specify in which graph you want to show, show some efforts where you are integrating this data.

Comment: in which ?high-charts or anything else ?

Comment: A fairly easy one. Try it out. https://canvasjs.com/javascript-charts/solid-dashed-line-chart/

Comment: Try d3js : http://bl.ocks.org/mstanaland/6100713

Comment: You can use- https://www.chartjs.org/